# Classify a list of element based on their attribute in R

Tags: r, classification

I have a list elements each element contain a list of text attribute like .

```
> list
[[1]]
 [1] "attribute 1"     
 [2] "attribute 2"     
 [3] "attribute 3"     

[[2]]
[1] "attribute 4"     
[2] "attribute 5" 
[3] "attribute 6" 

[[3]]
 [1] "attribute 1"     
 [2] "attribute 2"      

[[4]]
[1] "attribute 4"     
[2] "attribute 5"
[3] "attribute 6"
```

What classification or clustering algorithm (the simplest) can i apply to get this element classified based on similarity of their textual attribute.
to get results like : [1,3] in category 1 and [2,4] in category 2 .

Comment: Your desired output is not very clear. It is also better you'd provide a `dput` of your list instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Idea**

You could use `hclust` on the distance matrix. For that you would first need to transfrom your data into a matrix, calculate the distance and then do the hierarchical clustering on this matrix.

**Code**

```
l <- list(paste("attribute", 1:3),
          paste("attribute", 4:6),
          paste("attribute", 1:2),
          paste("attribute", 4:6))
allElem <- sort(unique(unlist(l)))
incidM <- do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(allElem %in% x)))
colnames(incidM) <- allElem
rownames(incidM) <- paste("Set", seq_len(NROW(incidM)))
dM <- dist(incidM)
hc <- hclust(dM)
plot(hc)
```

**Explanation**

First, you create a matrix which rows correspond to the elements in your list and rows to the unique values in your list. Each element is either `1` if the corresponding list element contain this attribute, or `0` otherwise.

```
incidM
#       attribute 1 attribute 2 attribute 3 attribute 4 attribute 5 attribute 6
# Set 1           1           1           1           0           0           0
# Set 2           0           0           0           1           1           1
# Set 3           1           1           0           0           0           0
# Set 4           0           0           0           1           1           1
```

Then, you can calculate the distance matrix between the rows and do the hierarchical clustering on that matrix. Finally you can plot the whole thing and you see indeed that Set 1 & 3 are similiar and 2 & 4.

[image]